# Return true if the elements of an array do not contain one or the other

Tags: java, beginner, array

I am gradually completing the CodingBat exercises for Java. [Here is the one](http://codingbat.com/prob/p136648) I just did:

> Given an array of ints, return true if it contains no 1's or it contains no 4's.

Here is my code:

```
public boolean no14(int[] nums) {

    int oneCount = 0;
    int fourCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] == 1) {
            oneCount++;
        }
        if (nums[i] == 4) {
            fourCount++;
        }
    }

    if (oneCount > 0 && fourCount > 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now, I am pretty unfamiliar with arrays, so I would just like to know if there is a simpler/shorter way of finding such information without setting a count for each number? Perhaps using a regular expression?

Comment: regex for this? now you have 3 problems, the original one, turning it into a regex and making a regex engine for an int array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JDK there's nothing, but with [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) you could do

```
List<Integer> list com.google.common.primitives.Ints.asList(nums);
return !(list.contains(1) && list.contains(4));
```

Obviously, converting `int[]` to something like `ArrayList<Integer>` would be a performance disaster. Fortunately, there's nothing like this, instead there's a [class implementing the `List` interface](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.java#L520) by accessing the primitive array. Bulk-methods like `contains` are optimized and lead to a simple loop with no boxing inside.

---

But seriously, feel free to stick with your loop, as there's not always such a trick available. What you could improve:

- You need no `xxxCount`, a simple `boolean containsXxx` would do. But this is no problem, having the count may be useful sometimes.
- You could use an early return. Whenever you find a 1, you can check if you have already a 4 and `return false` if so.

---

The only part I dislike is

```
if (oneCount > 0 && fourCount > 0) {
    return false;
}
return true;
```

You surely mean

```
return oneCount == 0 || fourCount == 0;
```

---

If performance was *very* important (which it rarely is), I'd try this

```
int i = 0;
int missing;
for (; ; i++) {
    if (i == nums.length) {
        return true;
    } else if (num[i] == 1) {
        missing = 4;
        break;
    } else if (num[i] == 4) {
        missing = 1;
        break;
    }
}
for (; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (nums[i] == missing) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

But as you can see, it's terribly long and not very readable. When embedded in a real code it may also be *slower* (due to inlining limit or whatever).

Comment: Really? You're going to convert the `int[]` array to a `List<Integer>`?

Comment: @rolfl Why not? It's not an `ArrayList`. See the [doc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#asList(int...)). It's less efficient than looping manually, but only by a small constant; the `contains` method is full speed.

Comment: Hmm, it is still not good, not as bad as I thought, but the instance overhead, and autoboxing additions put neat code in front of an ugly backend. I see that you do recommend an early-exit on finding both, hat suggestion is the most valuable part as far as I can tell. Unfortunately my down-vote is locked in until your post is edited...

Comment: @rolfl Edited. There's a single unboxing inside the call to `contains`, that's all.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, your naming is good. I never like `nums` as a name, but sometimes, like in this case, it's hard to see anything more descriptive. Perhaps just `numbers`. `no14` is also not a great name, though since this is testing something so specific, there probably aren't many candidates. `emptyOfOnesOrFours` or similar might be better, cumbersome as it is.

---

As for code, the algorithm is a good and clear start, but let's see if we can do any better with the code through refactoring.

First, we can see that there's actually there's actually a lot of the same code being done separately for 1 and 4. Imagine if you added, say, six more numbers to that list, and you'd see a lot of repetition emerging. So the first thing to do would be to extract that into a method:

```
private boolean contains(int[] numbers, int target) {
    int targetCount = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
        if(numbers[i] == target) {
            targetCount++
        }
    }
    if(targetCount > 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now that we've done this, we can see an obvious simplification:

```
private boolean contains(int[] numbers, int target) {

    for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
        if(numbers[i] == target) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now our original method can read much clearer:

```
public boolean emptyOfOnesOrFours(int[] numbers) {
    return !contains(numbers,1) || !contains(numbers,4);
}
```

(That's just about pushing the complexity of what I'd want in a single line, so depending on taste you could separate that out by first assigning the individual `contains` calls to booleans.)

Comment: It may actually have better performance, as each of the loops stop once they hit the expected value, and the cost of doing two small loops versus one larger loop isn't too big.

Comment: @MrTi Good point! I removed that last paragraph, since I think going into analysis of the more/less performant scenarios and their relative probabilities would be overkill.

Answer (score 1):

At first, I was curious why the question was phrased as "not containing 1 **or** 4", the stream-based solution here seems to suggest why:

```
public static boolean hasNoOneAndFour(int... values) {
    return Arrays.stream(values).filter(i -> i == 1 || i == 4).distinct().count() != 2;
}
```

Picking out only the values 1 and 4 (`filter(i -> i == 1 || i == 4)`) is understandable, how can one check that we have both 1 **and** 4 in the end? I went with a `distinct()` operation and then counting that we do not have **both** values...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to count ones and fours, since you can return false at the first sight of either one.

```
public boolean no14(int[] nums) {

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] == 1 || nums[i] == 4) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Assuming I understand the problem, you code is wrong.

Comment: @CamelFace Please read the question. No 1s **OR** no 4s.

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview, CamelFace. Please try to read the question carefully!

Comment: I agree with others, that you misread the question slightly, but you have also seen an optimization that nobody else has, just implemented it wrong. +1 for the fail-faster suggestion.

Comment: I think the question should be phrased as "no 1s and 4s"...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to include a library for such simple problem, do it this way:

```
static boolean no14(int[] ints){
    // make copy if you don't wont to modify the input
    int[] copy = ints.clone();

    Arrays.sort(copy); // O(n log n)

    return Arrays.binarySearch(ints, 1) >= 0 && Arrays.binarySearch(ints, 4) >= 0;
}
```

If your input is small, do not worry about sorting.